# Recordatorios si una celda coincide con una fecha en Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una alerta que recuerde a las personas a enviar un reporte semanal cuando determinadas fechas (que están seleccionadas en la columna BA) están igualadas con el día actual.

El problema es que mi caja de mensaje no se está mostrando, y a pesar de que el código parece ser muy simple, no estoy encontrando una solución al problema. Cambié el día en mi computadora para probar y no pasó nada.

El código es el siguiente:

```
Sub ReportReminder()

    If Date = Sheets(1).Cell("BA15").Value Then
        MsgBox ("Enviar reporte semanal")
    ElseIf Date = Sheets(1).Cell("BA21").Value Then
        MsgBox ("Enviar reporte semanal")
    ElseIf Date = Sheets(1).Cell("BA27").Value Then
        MsgBox ("Enviar reporte semanal")
    ElseIf Date = Sheets(1).Cell("BA33").Value Then
        MsgBox ("Enviar reporte semanal")
    End If

End Sub
```

Cualquier otro dato que necesiten háganme saber.

Comment: has probado poniendo `"else Msgbox ("ninguno de los anteriores")"` antes del `end if` para saber que tus comprobaciones están bien? igual no se cumple ninguna

Comment: ¿Desde dónde se dispara este método?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Excel estás usando?

Comment: ¿En qué formato está la fecha en la columna BA?

Answer (score 1):

No indicas la versión de Office / Excel que estás usando; sin embargo pongo una solución para Excel 2010 o superior.

Como alguien preguntó en los comentarios, tampoco estás indicando cómo disparas el código que usaste; eso es importante, porque si simplemente está definido el método en algún módulo VBA, Excel nunca ejecutará el código: tienes que asociarlo a algún evento (cambio) para que funcione.

El siguiente código hace la comprobación que necesitas cuando se da un cambio en la hoja especificada; es una variación de tu propio código, agregando validación de errores y usando un arreglo con los valores de las celdas que necesitas comprobar (esto permitiría agregar más celdas a la validación de manera sencilla):

```vb
Dim celdas(1 To 4) As Variant        'matriz o arreglo de celdas a comprobar
                                     '(podría incrementarse su tamaño para incluir otras)
Dim ws As Worksheet                  'hoja de trabajo donde se realizará la comprobación

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Salir

    ' Inicializar datos para comprobación
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    celdas(1) = ws.Range("BA15").Value
    celdas(2) = ws.Range("BA21").Value
    celdas(3) = ws.Range("BA27").Value
    celdas(4) = ws.Range("BA33").Value

    Dim fecha As Date
    fecha = Date

    ' Determinar si se muestra el mensaje de reporte, buscando en todas las celdas
    For x = 1 To UBound(celdas)
        If celdas(x) = fecha Then
            ' Mostrar mensaje y salir del ciclo
            MsgBox "Enviar reporte semanal."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub

Salir:
    ' Se generó un error, simplemente salir (aquí podría mostrarse un mensaje)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

El único problema con el código es que se estará ejecutando cada vez que se hace *cualquier* cambio en la hoja (que es básicamente lo que indicas en tu pregunta); si existen muchos datos en ella y/o fórmulas, entonces esto podría generar un cuello de botella; por lo tanto debes ser cuidadoso con eso. Una alternativa sería integrar un botón para que los usuarios lancen la verificación de manera manual.

El código debe incluirse en la hoja de Excel donde vas a hacer la validación; si la hoja no es la primera, entonces también debes cambiar la línea `Set ws = Worksheets(1)` para indicar la hoja específica donde está tu información.

La ventana VBA de tu código debería mostrarse de manera similar a la imagen que pongo a continuación:

[image: Código de hoja de Excel]

Espero que te sirva la solución. Saludos.